# Why does QGIS not show legend when layer has multiple styles

Tags: qgis, wms, legend, getlegendgraphic

When using QGIS with layers that have one style it loads the legend of that style automatically, which is what I want. But when I have a layer with multiple styles when I load the default layer it does not show the legend. When I load specific layers (including the default layer) it does show a legend.

Why does QGIS do this? Is this a bug in QGIS or is this something I can tweak in the WMS XML?

For example this WMS: https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/netcapaciteit/wms/v1_0

[image: No legend]

When I load the style directly (thus QGIS picks the first style) it does not show the legend. But when I select the first style manually like this:

[image: Select layer manual]

[image: Select layer manual 2]

[image: Tada there is a legend]

As you can see now there is a legend. Why does QGIS not load the legend of the default style?

Comment: I'm assuming it's because it needs the style name to make the GetLegendGraphic request (to get the legend) and it can't guess it from all the named styles in layer `IndicatiefVerzorgingsgebied`, but with layer `Stations` there is only one style name so it can

Comment: It just means that you need to select the style name when loading the Layer in QGIS